# Bindings not updating while processes are running (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
public string Something
{
    get { return _something.something; }
    set
    {
        _something.something = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Something");
    }
}
```

An example of a ViewModel method

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Something}" />
```

I have a method that goes through a list of processes and after each it calls the 'Something,' but the View bound to 'Something' doesn't get updated periodically.

Any suggestions as to why this could be? Do I need to create a separate thread for the calls?

UPDATE: Using Async fixed it.

Comment: You may wish to do your long running process asynchronously, if the UI thread is busy then the view will not update.

Comment: Why are you binding a ListBox to a String?

Comment: That's a good idea, but... I'm having trouble changing it to async. Which reference, if any, do I need for that? Does it use System.Threading?

@Blam It's a typo. Sorry.

Comment: @Blam No reason. Async worked. 

Thanks, BenRobinson, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the `Mode` property on binding level ? For example

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Something, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```